# PHP while loop on web server acts differently

Tags: php, themoviedb-api

I'm working on a movie rating site, and I put the code on my web server. The code works fine on my local web server, but not on my online hosting.

The problem is that there's a while loop that executes differently on the two servers. I have info for movies in my database (eg. title, image, ELO) and I loop through them with `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and show them sorted by rank on my leaderboard page.

```php
while ($rowselectmovies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultselectmovies)) {
    $movie = $repository->load($rowselectmovies['id']);

    foreach ($movie->getImages()->filter(
        function ($key, $value) {
            if ($value->getIso6391() == 'en' && $value instanceof \Tmdb\Model\Image\PosterImage) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    ) as $image) {
        $imagehtml = $imageHelper->getHtml($image, 'w154', 100);
        break;
    }

    if ($i > 3) {
        $margin = "uk-margin-small";
    } else {
        $margin = "uk-margin-small-bottom";
    }

    echo "<div class='uk-card uk-card-secondary uk-card-body uk-padding-small movie-container " . $margin . " uk-width-1-3'><h2 class='uk-display-inline-block uk-padding-small'>" . $i . "</h2> " . $rowselectmovies['name'] . "<div class='uk-float-right'>" . $imagehtml . "</div></div>";

    if (($i) % 3 == 0) {
        echo '<hr>';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

On the local server, this code shows all 50 movies in the database, but on the online hosting, it only shows 6 or 7, and the number seems to change as I rate movies. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you double check that all 50 movies exist in the database?

Comment: Also, try adding an echo/var dump on the first line in the query loop to make sure your filtering isn't removing them.

Comment: Thanks, I used var dump, and it showed me that some of my id's were wrong in my database